# Using attributes from one class inside of another one

Tags: python, console

I'm working on a small fighting game as a learning experience and right now I'm working on implementing a store where you can buy weapons.
I decided to use a class for the store and have everything that you can do in it as a class method. But I'm unsure how to get all the data from my `Weapon` class and use it in the `Store` class. It's not pretty but here's what I have so far:

Sorry for misspelling tier.

```
class Item(object):
    '''Anything that can be used or equiped.'''
    def __init__(self, _id, desc, cost):
        self._id = _id
        self.desc = desc
        self.cost = cost

class Weapon(Item):
    def __init__(self, _id, desc, dam):
        self._id = _id
        self.desc = desc
        self.dam = dam

def __str__(self):
    return self._id

class Store(object):

dagger = Weapon('Dagger', 'A small knife. Weak but quick.', 'd4')
s_sword = Weapon('Short Sword', 'A small sword. Weak but quick.', 'd6')
l_sword = Weapon('Long Sword', 'A normal sword. Very versatile.', 'd8')
g_sword = Weapon('Great Sword', 'A powerful sword. Really heavy.', 'd10')

w_teir_1 = [dagger, s_sword, l_sword]
w_teir_2 = [w_teir_1, g_sword]

def intro(self):
    print 'Welcome, what would you like to browse?'
    print '(Items, weapons, armor)'
    choice = raw_input(':> ')
    if choice == 'weapons':
        self.show_weapons(self.w_teir_1)

def show_weapons(self, teir):
    for weapon in teir:
        i = 1
        print str(i), '.', teir._id
        i += 1
    raw_input()
```

I can't get the `show_weapon` function to print the _id for the weapon. All I can do is get it to print the raw object data.

Edit: I've figured out how to display the `_id` of the weapon when I'm passing the list `w_teir_1` through the `show_weapons` method. But when I attempt to push `w_teir_2` through, I get this error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_id'`

Comment: try `print str(i), '.', weapon._id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the last `print` stmt like below, since you're iterating over a list. `_id` attribute exists only for the elements which exists inside that list.

```
print str(i), '.', weapon._id
```

or

```
print str(i) +  '.' +  weapon._id
```

Update:

```
def show_weapons(self, teir):
    for weapon in teir:
        if isinstance(weapon, list):
            for w in weapon:
                i = 1
                print str(i), '.', w._id
                i += 1
                raw_input()
        else:
            i = 1
            print str(i), '.', weapon._id
            i += 1
            raw_input()
```

Comment: Hm, oh great, now I get a `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_id'
`

Comment: The only thing I changes was the print line in `show_weapons`. I changed it to: `print str(i), '.', weapon._id`

Comment: post the full stack trace in your question. Is that it has to do something with private variable?

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to add more tiers exactly the same way I'm doing it above. Like, `tier_3 = [tier_1, tier_2, weapon, ect]`? I'm getting the same error that I was last time when I try this. Do I have to do another if?

Comment: you need to understand the concept. `tier` we are passing to that function may or maynot contain the combination of list or Weapon objects. If it's  a list then it must contain only weapon objects. So by invoking the `_id` attrib on each elem on that list should work. If it's not a list then it must be a Weapon odj. So you may directly invoke the `_id` attrib.